# VBA - get all file properties

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get properties from all files in a folder. I have this already working for a fixed number of properties, my only concern is to find the last property's index, used in `GetDetailsOf` method, so that I can have all properties listed.

Function below returns count of properties, but is incorrect, because it's based on last non-empty property name. There are however a few indices with empty names (not sure if they can have values), followed by another indices which have property name with normal string.

I also tried `On Error Resume Next` with error indicating that last index has already been used, but there never was an error and it resulted in an endless loop, apparently `GetDetailsOf` will accept every long >=0.

I would also like to know if the number of file properties is the same for each folder on one machine.

EDIT: I may have not clearly expressed it, what I want is to get index of last property name, so that I can check values for all existing properties.

EDIT 2: Here's a link to my file, listing properties for all files in selected folder and subfolders of all levels. There may be some not handled bugs (I already sorted one with shortcuts crashing macro), Windows path length limit comes to my mind, but it will in general work for selected folder.

Main function of interest is CountProperties in list_properties module. It decides on how many property columns will be returned.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TRIZJoGnHXs9LJtxDBj9rp27ngkects-

```
Function CountProperties(ByRef FldPath) As Long

Dim objShell As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim testStr As String
Dim propertyCnt As Long

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(Left(FldPath, Len(FldPath) - 1)) 'no slash in the end

Do
    testStr = vbNullString      
    testStr = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.Items, propertyCnt)      
    If testStr = vbNullString Then Exit Do
    propertyCnt = propertyCnt + 1
Loop

CountProperties = propertyCnt

End Function
```

Comment: The number and order is OS dependent, but not sure if on the OS where the folder is created or maybe where the partition is formatted. On Windows 10 they are up to 315, on Vista less than 300, and on XP a lot less. `If objFolder.GetDetailsOf(, propertyCnt) = ""` is enough to check for the last property. The only exception that I know of that has value but no name is -1.

Comment: Thanks for feedback on how it looks on different systems. I have Windows 7 and it's 0 to 299. From about 290 there are 4 empty names.

Comment: Ah yes, I get a lot of missing property names at -1, 54,165 to 166, 200 to 202, 213, 291, and from 316. I am not aware of any better way to get the properties count.

Comment: I posted an idea in my answer, we can assume there won't be more than for example 500 properties and go backwards to check last populated name on one of folders, as  `GetDetailsOf` doesn't limit the index parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running some code to learn more about file properties obtained via `GetDetailsOf`, especially checking property names of thousands of folders on C, here is what I've found out (Windows 7):

- Number of property names is constant for all these folders and all of them appear in the same order.
- The maximum index of non-empty string property was 299 (0 to 299). There were 4 empty string names several indices near the end. @Slai claims that the number varies depending on Windows version, as new are added with another releases or updates.

I think that checking one folder with `GetDetailsOf` let's say from 500 to 0 and seeing index of 1st not empty name would be the way to find last index.

I would however recommend getting only needed properties, because processing time depends heavily on file type and while for some 50 GB directories containing 1500 files I could get 300 property values for all files in a few seconds, a directory with even less files, but all mp3, took minutes.

Comment: Interesting. What does 4 empty string names mean? Are these particular fields?

Comment: I have just realized that these 4 empty strings separate names in language according to my regional settings and 9 other names in English.

Answer (score 4):

I am not entirely clear what the end goal of this is but the following should extract all the info you need.

Includes: Count of total set properties by file, folder count of set properties , each file's extended properties values and whether all files in a folder have the same number of properties with assigned values. I'd probably re-factor the function but await your feedback.

**Note:**

I chose an array to be returned as I thought you might end up comparing folders and this way you can simply create a collection/dictionary of the returned arrays using the folder paths as keys. You can then access and compare items within the arrays across folders.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

''******************************************************************
'' folderInfo returns:
'' folderInfo(0) = PATH_FOLDER - folder path used
'' folderInfo(1) = AllFileProperties - Dictionary of arrays containing all the file properties of each file within the folder
'' folderInfo(2) = totalPropertiesSetInFolder - total count of extended properties <> vbNullString in the folder
'' folderInfo(3) = filePropertyCounts - dictionary of each file with its respective set property count
'' folderInfo(4) = AllFilesHaveSamePropertyCount - Boolean to say if all files in folder have same # extended properties set

''******************************************************************
Public Sub test()

    Const PATH_FOLDER As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\TestFolder\"
    Dim resultsArray()
    resultsArray() = folderInfo(PATH_FOLDER) '<== All the info is now returned here

''***************************************************************************************
       '' Examples of extracting the retrieved information from the array

''***************************************************************************************    

    'Example: folderInfo(0) = folderPath
    Debug.Print "Folderpath = " & resultsArray(0)
    Debug.Print String$(20, Chr$(60))
    Debug.Print vbNewLine

''***************************************************************************************

    'Example: folderInfo(1) = AllFileProperties
    Debug.Print "AllFileProperties:"
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dict = resultsArray(1)

    Dim key As Variant, arr(), i As Long

    For Each key In dict.keys
        Debug.Print "FileName = " & key
        arr() = dict(key)
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            Debug.Print arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2)
        Next i

        Debug.Print String$(20, Chr$(60))
        Debug.Print vbNewLine
    Next key

''***************************************************************************************

    ''Example: folderInfo(2) = totalPropertiesSetInFolder
    MsgBox "Total properties set in folder = " & resultsArray(2)


''***************************************************************************************

    ''Example: folderInfo(3) = filePropertyCounts
    Dim dict2 As Object
    Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dict2 = resultsArray(3)

    Dim key2 As Variant

    For Each key2 In dict2.keys
        Debug.Print key2 & " set property count = " & dict2(key2)
    Next key2

''***************************************************************************************
    ''Example: folderInfo(4) = AllFilesHaveSamePropertyCount
    MsgBox "All files have the same # of set properties? = " & resultsArray(4)

End Sub

Public Function folderInfo(ByVal PATH_FOLDER As String) As Variant

    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(Left$(PATH_FOLDER, Len(PATH_FOLDER) - 1))

    'Retrieving Extended File Properties
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrHeaders(35)

    For i = 0 To 34
        arrHeaders(i) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.items, i)
    Next

    Dim fileName As Object, setPropertyCount As Long, filePropertyCounts As Object, totalPropertiesSetInFolder As Long
    Set filePropertyCounts = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim AllFileProperties As Object
    Set AllFileProperties = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each fileName In objFolder.items
        setPropertyCount = 0
        Dim fileProperties(0 To 35, 0 To 35)
        fileProperties(0, 0) = fileName
        For i = 0 To 34
            If objFolder.GetDetailsOf(fileName, i) <> vbNullString Then setPropertyCount = setPropertyCount + 1
             fileProperties(i + 1, 1) = arrHeaders(i)
             fileProperties(i + 1, 2) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(fileName, i)

            '            Debug.Print i & vbTab & arrHeaders(i) _
            '                      & ": " & objFolder.GetDetailsOf(fileName, i)
            '            Debug.Print vbNewLine
        Next i
        'Debug.Print fileName & ": setpropertyCount = " & setPropertyCount
        filePropertyCounts.Add fileName.Name, setPropertyCount

        AllFileProperties.Add fileName.Name, fileProperties
    Next fileName

    totalPropertiesSetInFolder = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(filePropertyCounts.items)

    folderInfo = Array(PATH_FOLDER, AllFileProperties, totalPropertiesSetInFolder, filePropertyCounts, AllFilesHaveSamePropertyCount(filePropertyCounts))

End Function

Public Function AllFilesHaveSamePropertyCount(ByVal filePropertyCounts As Object) As Boolean

    AllFilesHaveSamePropertyCount = True
    Dim key As Variant

    For Each key In filePropertyCounts.Keys
        If filePropertyCounts(key) <> Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(filePropertyCounts.items) Then
            AllFilesHaveSamePropertyCount = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next key

End Function
```

**Example run:**

[image: Example run]

**Reference:**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176615.aspx

Comment: Any feedback on this? I put some effort into writing for you.

Comment: I appreciate it, but I don't always have time to do full tests during workweek. I'm a rather meticulous person and didn't want to respond or mark as an answer until I have checked all the aspects.

Comment: No problem about downvote, what I really care about is to get solution and You already committed some time to help me. The link is very helpful, now I know where do all fixed number property checks in internet codes come from. Unfortunately I could be not clear enough, I've put an edit to my initial post. What I seek is to go past these properties listed in documentation, because there are many more and see how many of them (not values, property names) there are and if this number varies depending on the folder. Thanks to the link I'm sure that these start properties will always be same.

Comment: Ah... so there are more than 35 properties? Can you give an example of one please? Or are you referring to not just "extended" properties but all properties of a file?

Comment: The names vary depending on local language for machine. You can use safely perhaps any long value >=0 to list them. On test folder I has about 300 of them displayed. My main issue is that I can enter index = 500 and macro will still go on and list all non-existing properties as null strings. I'm not sure what is exact scope of Extended Properties, but I would like to get all properties obtainable with `GetDetailsOf` method.

Comment: Are you referring specifically to extended properties of a file ?

Comment: I will attach my current file, so that I don't keep You guessing. Main function of interest is CountProperties in list_properties module. It decides on how many property columns will be returned. You can test with setting it arbitrarily to let's 300 and see the difference, because now the counter stops whenever property name is empty, but this is a trap, after a while there are another property names.

Comment: I see where you are coming from. See this: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DocProp.aspx There were also a lot of  other things I noticed with your code so you might consider the following tool as helpful to inspect your code: http://rubberduckvba.com/

Comment: I've checked the 1st link before doing my own code actually, but I always refuse all solutions using external files, because of problems which can appear on different machines and usually required TeamViewer assistance when my non-IT Client has no clue what to do when what he gets is not a single Excel file. I've added as an answer what I found out during some checks.