# Microsoft Voice Recorder Date, Time and Duration

Tags: vba, ms-access, audio

Microsoft's Voice Recorder, in Windows 10, Stores recording in a Recordings File that is in Documents Folder. On the Voice Recorder app screen the Date, Time and Duration of recording is displayed.  Is there a way to get the Date, Time and Duration from the entries in the Voice Recorder File?

Want to get the timestamp of recordings saved by the Voice recorder programmatically for use in an ACCESS database, but the save records don't indicate a timestamp.  I can't find a way of getting that information.

Comment: I see each recording as a single file stored on my laptop in folder "\Documents\Sound recordings". Programmatically pulling file properties is a common topic. Relevant property index numbers are:  Duration = 43; Date = 189; I don't see a property for Time but maybe just extract that from Date or DateCreated = 4, both of which include time components and show same value.

Comment: Start with review of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262556/vba-get-all-file-properties

Comment: I was able to select those properties for display in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Also, https://www.devhut.net/how-to-retrieve-a-files-properties-with-vba/